# how to get seconds out of time column in csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Loaded in a csv file with start time and end time as two of the columns I want to divide one of the columns by a number how do I do this?

Comment: Show the format of your data, along with what code you have tried.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What is the format of the column?  What does it mean to divide a time by a number?  For instance, what is 3:14:59 pm / 2?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist\](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

as others have mentioned some more info will help, you can not really *divide* a 'start_time' by a number. If the start time is an integer timestamp then yes. Try something like this.

```python
import pandas as pd

THE_DIVISOR = 25342
# data is like 
# station_id, start_time, end_time  
# (INT), (epoch timestamp), (epoch timestamp)

df = pd.read_csv('dobis.csv')
print df.head()

# now to divide a column by another number
# use vectorization
df['divided_timed'] = df['start_time'] / THE_DIVISOR

# can do other things too, great thing about python is that
# most of the time you can just try something and 
# usually the logical sounding code just works.

df['extra_time'] = (df['start_time'] * 2340834) + (df['end_time'] / 2340)
```